# Plot line graph with matplotlib python for a pivot table

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I have a pivot table which looks like the one shown below. I want to plot a line graph showing the scores with days on the x axis and scores on the y axis.

I have tried the below

```
table = pd.pivot_table(test, values='scores', index='day', columns='month')
chart = table.plot(xticks = index,kind='line', linewidth=3.0)
```

Pivot table
[image]

Answer (score 0):

When I try to reproduce this, I get an error that index is not defined. Because I don't have your data, I'm not sure that's your problem as well so if you have a different problem, please say what your program does properly and what it doesn't, give us some info.

Just deleting the `xticks = index` part does the job for me. So try this:

```
table = pd.pivot_table(test, values='scores', index='day', columns='month')
chart = table.plot(kind='line', linewidth=3.0)
```

It will automatically use the `day` column for the x-axis and make a separate line per month with the score as y-value.

Comment: I tried this. But its not showing the labels on the x axis.